# Use of ng-controller in partial view doesn't work in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ajax, razor, asp.net-ajax

I can't manage to use my angular controller in a partial view with ASP.NET
It works well when I'm in normal view but when I want to use it in partial view it just doesn't work (nothing in console in firefox).

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

**TestController**

```
app.controller("testController",
    function($scope) {
        $scope.test = "test";
    });
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="~/assets/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/assets/js/angular/app.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="app">
            @Renderbody()
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script src="~/assets/js/angular/testController.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="testController">

    {{test}}

    @Ajax.ActionLink("Test", "TestAction",
                     "TestController",
                     new { },
                     new AjaxOptions
                     {
                        UpdateTargetId = "partialView",
                     },
                     new { });

    <div id="partialView">
    </div>
</div>
```

**_Partial.cshtml**

```
<p>{{test}}</p>
```

this won't work, I tried this and I tried putting the `ng-controller` in both views.

**TestController.cs**

```
public ActionResult TestAction(){
    return PartialView("_Partial.cshtml");
}
```

I must have missed something but I can't figure out what.